# TestNG passing different sets of parameter in TestNG xml

Tags: testng

Is it possible to pass different sets of values to a parameter in TestNG xml.

```
<test name="Google on FF" >
<parameter name="browser" value="FF"></parameter>
<parameter name="browser" value="IE"></parameter>
<classes>
<class name="Test" />
</classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you will have to create separate tests for that or consider using a [factory](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories)

```
<test name="test" >
<parameter name="browser" value="ff"></parameter>
    <classes>
       <class name="com.nv.tests.TestClass1" />
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="test" >
<parameter name="browser" value="ie"></parameter>
    <classes>
       <class name="com.nv.tests.TestClass1" />
    </classes>
</test>
```